# How many 'offensive' flags are needed to delete a post?

Tags: support

I just stumbled on a clearly offensive post and flagged is as such. Now it seems that every 'offensive' flag creates one downvote, so I guess it has 4 flags already but is still visible.

Hence my question: How many flags are needed for deletion?

Comment: Could you post a link to it?

Comment: @CarlH I would not :-)

Answer (score 3):

6 by normal users, one by a moderator...